# Evaluation of Inhabitants on/of/based on the Influence of Media?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality, expressions, translation

I'm currently translating an abstract for personal purposes, but I'm not sure how I'd translate this part. I translated it as this:

> Self-Evaluation of Inhabitants **on (the)** Influence of Media (the rest is not important)

What I want to know is if it's better to put something else instead of on, *of* sounds off to me, *based on* might be fine, *on the topic of* sounds like there's too much happening.

Also, if there's maybe a better way to say evaluation of inhabitants (maybe assessment?) or maybe a way it sounds better (can I say Inhabitant Evaluation?), please let me know.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Are the inhabitants evaluating the influence of the media on themselves? You could say "Self-assessment of influence of media on inhabitants".

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for the suggestion, that does sound more natural! :)

Comment: *An Inhabitant Assessment of Media Influence* seems like a simpler version. Although I'm not clear on the context of *inhabitant*. All inhabitants, some, or one? And of what or where? Is *residents* or *locals* a better word? Perhaps even *A Neighbourhood Assessment of Media Influence*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a translation question where the source is neither specified nor in English.